# fetchmail says I have no mail

Tags: mutt, dotfiles, fetchmail

[image]

here's the output of running fetchmail -v

my .fetchmailrc looks like this

```
poll pop.gmail.com                   
with proto POP3                      
user 'username'        
there with password 'password'        
is 'name' here                              
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"        
options                                                             
keep                                 
fetchall
ssl                                  
sslcertck                            
sslcertpath /etc/ssl/certs
```

Any idea what's wrong? I do in fact have new mail.

Comment: I believe you can run fetchmail with multible "v"s, such as -vv, this should expose further debug logs

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to get most everything straightened out with this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail